# Regex: Parse streetname/number

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing

C#/.NET 2.0

I need to parse a string containing the street name and the house no in two separate values.

```
in: "Streetname 1a"         out:  "streetname"  "1a"
    "Street name 1a"              "street name" "1a"
    "Street name 1 a"             "street name" "1 a"
```

My first choice was to split the string where I found a " " char but that will not work for the second case.

```
result[0] = trimmedInput.Substring(0, splitPosition).Trim();
result[1] = trimmedInput.Substring(splitPosition + 1).Trim();
```

What is the best way to do this? Can I use regular expressions?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the data stored? Can't you just persist it differently, in its preferable format?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`^(.+)\s(\S+)$` should do the trick

EDIT: this will work is the house number can't have spaces in it. Otherwise this problem can't be solved programmatically since the program will never know the semantics of string tokens.

House addresses are messy and inconsistent. I worked with address data and honestly, if you don't have the data in normalized form, you're basically screwed.

`^(.+)\s(\d+(\s*[^\d\s]+)*)$` will cover some more cases, but pattern like that is a can of worms if I ever saw one.

Comment: @thedev: I think my last edit will pass all 3 tests but it will inevitably fail at some others that you can't even think of at the moment.

Comment: the last edit passes these 3 tests... it also outputs a value witch is allways "a" in these cases, can we remove this third val ?

Comment: @thedev: what do you mean? I suppose you need Groups[1] and Groups[2]

Comment: I also get Groups[3] for the last regex

Comment: Yeah I know, but you will always get it. Just use the ones you need.

Answer (score 2):

You have to more clearly define the pattern you're looking for, assuming there even is one. There needs to be some general observations you can make that will always hold:

- A street address consists of a name and a number.
- The name always appears first.
- The name consists of one or more words, separated by spaces.
- The number is a number followed by an optional letter.

From a comment, the last point isn't strictly true because the number & letter portion of the street number can be separated by whitespace.

If you can't guarantee the order of the street name & number, and also that the words in the street name do not contain numbers, then I'm not really sure that anything is going to help you.

The following regex should cover most cases:

```
Regex reggie = new Regex(@"^(?<name>\w[\s\w]+?)\s*(?<num>\d+\s*[a-z]?)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Using \w is a bad idea. Some french steets like "Rue d'Alembert" won't qualify, etc.

Comment: Then you have to consider ’ (&#146;) as well.

Answer (score 2):

As Dyppl stated, street addresses are messy.  But, if your address data represents US addresses and you have the complete address (including city, state, and/or ZIP Code) you could use an address verification service to parse (and verify!) and standardize the components.  I work for [SmartyStreets](http://www.smartystreets.com), an address verification provider.  Here's a quick C# example I wrote a while back that calls our LiveAddress API:

https://github.com/smartystreets/LiveAddressSamples/blob/master/c-sharp/street-address.cs

Here's the resulting output for that example (notice that the street name and primary number are parsed in the "components" section):

```
[
    {
        "input_index": 0,
        "candidate_index": 0,
        "delivery_line_1": "3214 N University Ave",
        "last_line": "Provo UT 84604-4405",
        "delivery_point_barcode": "846044405140",
        "components": {
            "primary_number": "3214",
            "street_predirection": "N",
            "street_name": "University",
            "street_suffix": "Ave",
            "city_name": "Provo",
            "state_abbreviation": "UT",
            "zipcode": "84604",
            "plus4_code": "4405",
            "delivery_point": "14",
            "delivery_point_check_digit": "0"
        },
        "metadata": {
            "record_type": "S",
            "county_fips": "49049",
            "county_name": "Utah",
            "carrier_route": "C016",
            "congressional_district": "03",
            "latitude": 40.27586,
            "longitude": -111.6576,
            "precision": "Zip9"
        },
        "analysis": {
            "dpv_match_code": "Y",
            "dpv_footnotes": "AABBR1",
            "dpv_cmra": "Y",
            "dpv_vacant": "N",
            "ews_match": false
        }
    }
]
```

Here's a link that explains all the fields:

http://wiki.smartystreets.com/liveaddress_api_users_guide#json-responses

EDIT: included latitude/longitude fields (newly released).

Comment: Just USPS addresses for now.  Check out www.worldaddresses.com or www.strikeiron.com for international address processing.

Comment: You can try to regex all you want, but unless you can get a standardized address object back from an address standardization service, it will be very hard, and very difficult to guarantee correctness

Answer (score 0):

At first you should try to find the number by using [`String.LastIndexOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d.aspx) to split at a possible position.

Afterwards you should check if any character within this last group contains any digits like `splittedValue.Any(c => Char.IsDigit(c));`. So if you find any numbers within this last group you can be pretty sure, that you did the split correct, but maybe there are addresses out there that doesn't match this behaviour.

#### Update

If you really have such noisy data which must be normalized i think you can't do anything better then @Dyppl said and using some complicated regular expression which must evolve by samples you get that won't work.

Comment: another possibility for the input string would be: "street name 1 a" and in this case I would also get the wrong output

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming all you "addresses" will be formatted in at least one of the ways mentioned above.

```
string address = "Streetname 1a"

string street = Regex.Replace(address, "^[^0-9]+", "");

string number = address.Replace(street, "");
```

Then trim both values.

Comment: interesting, if we could exclude the number this might work. Considering the street name does not contain any digits

Comment: I have update the regex to something that might work (i.e. exclude the nuber) :)

Comment: You do realize that there are street names with numbers in them, right? Like, in New York

Comment: Yes, I realize this :) thats why I said "This is assuming all you "addresses" will be formatted in at least one of the ways mentioned above." 

Also, I think everyone realizes that this problem is unsolvable given the hundreds of different formats an address could be in. I'm simply providing an easy solution in case the OP only needs to cover the formats he provided as examples.

Comment: @Craigt: okay, no offense was intended

Comment: @Dyppl - no probs :)... @thedev ... I have updated the regex, should work now?